# Loading resources from external files

Tags: android

I am working on a localization strategy for our Android product. Once the core product is installed, I would like the user to be able to download additional language packs. Our resources are mainly strings. Essentially, I would like to keep the external file in xml format, similar to how it is done for embedded resources. This way, the translators can also test their translations right away and there won't be any need for sending them back-n-forth.

I am wondering if anyone has done something similar? The biggest challenge I see is that for embedded resources, the key gets converted to a numeric value. For example, getString(R.string.hello) may not work.

On second thought, it would be nice if I can compile the external resource file, similar to what Android framework does when building the .apk file.

Comment: Were you able to make it done? I have a similar problem to. Let us know if you get any way out, will be a great help!!